# TCPDump / libpcap - find memory location of payload data

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming, libpcap, tcpdump

I am trying to view http traffic going to and from my loopback network adapter using libpcap. I just beginning with network programming and completely new to this library. Thanks to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129532/libpcap-packet-ip-header-length-is-zero-bytes-with-loopback-tcp-requests) I received previously I have been successful at detecting the link-layer type on my machine's "lo0" adapter (Mac OSx).

```
//lookup link-layer header type
link_layer_type = pcap_datalink(handle);
if(link_layer_type == DLT_NULL){
    printf("DLT_NULL"); // this true in the case of "lo0"
}
```

The [Programming with Pcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) guide makes the assumption that each packet will contain an ethernet header. So the logic used to find a packet's payload is as follows:

```
 ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);
    ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);
    size_ip = IP_HL(ip)*4;
    if (size_ip < 20) {
        printf("   * Invalid IP header length: %u bytes\n", size_ip);
        return;
    }
    tcp = (struct sniff_tcp*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip);
    size_tcp = TH_OFF(tcp)*4;
    if (size_tcp < 20) {
        printf("   * Invalid TCP header length: %u bytes\n", size_tcp);
        return;
    }
}

payload = (u_char *)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip + size_tcp);
```

This logic is clearing not going to work when inspecting the contents of packet originating from the loopback interface where an ethernet header does not exists. The [Link-Layer Header Types documentation](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) states that a Link-Layer type of "DTL_NULL" contains a 4 byte header which consist of a PF_ value containing the network-layer protocol (I'm guess IPv4 in my case).

Given the above information.. how can I properly locate the packet's payload location?

Any guidance or information would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Given the above information.. how can I properly locate the packet's payload location?

For `DLT_NULL`, your program should extract the first 4 bytes of the packet data as a 32-bit number.  If you're doing a live capture, you can extract it in the host's byte order and compare it against your OS's values of `AF_INET` and `AF_INET6` (if it has an `AF_INET6` definition; these days, most current OS versions should, as they should support IPv6); if you're reading a capture file, you'd need to byte-swap the value if `pcap_is_swapped()` returns a non-zero value (you can also use it for live captures; it always returns zero for live captures), and you'll need to compare against several different "IPv6" values (24, 28, and 30), each of which mean "IPv6" on some particular OS (fortunately, `AF_INET` is 2 on all OSes that support `DLT_NULL`, as they all took that value from 4.2BSD).

If the value is the IPv4 value (2, as per the above), then after those 4 bytes you have the IPv4 header for the packet.  If it's one of the IPv6 values, then after those 4 bytes you have the *IPv6* header for the packet.  If it's not any of those values, it's some other protocol.